# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type tiagov.rideabike1.Model.Fretes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUi to populate one RecyclerView, but when I start the app nothing show up. I see a lot tutorials and videos but nothing work, maybe is a dumb question but I am new on android, here is all the code I am using:

Here is the model class

```
public class Fretes {

    private String mColeta;
    private String mEntrega;
    private String mStatus;


public Fretes() {

    }
    public Fretes(String mColetaLat, String mColetaLong, String mEntregaLat, String mEntregaLong, String mStatus) {
        this.mColeta= mColetaLat;
        this.mEntrega = mEntregaLat;
        this.mStatus = mStatus;
    }

    public String getmColeta() {
        return mColeta;
    }

    public void setmColeta(String mColetaLat) {
        this.mColeta = mColeta;
    }

    public String getmEntrega() {
        return mEntrega;
    }

    public void setmEntrega(String mEntrega) {
        this.mEntrega = mEntrega;
    }


    public String getmStatus() {
        return mStatus;
    }

    public void setmStatus(String mStatus) {
        this.mStatus = mStatus;
    }
}
```

Here is the holder class

```
public class FretesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView text_coleta;
    private final TextView text_entrega;
    private final TextView text_status;

    public FretesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        text_coleta = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_coleta);
        text_entrega = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_entrega);
        text_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_status);

    }

    public void setText_coleta(String coleta){
        setText_coleta(coleta);
    }

    public void setText_entrega(String entrega){ setText_entrega(entrega); }

    public void setText_status(String status){ setText_status(status); }
public class FretesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView text_coleta;
    private final TextView text_entrega;
    private final TextView text_status;

    public FretesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        text_coleta = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_coleta);
        text_entrega = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_entrega);
        text_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_status);

    }

    public void setText_coleta(String coleta){
        setText_coleta(coleta);
    }

    public void setText_entrega(String entrega){ setText_entrega(entrega); }

    public void setText_status(String status){ setText_status(status); }
}
```

And here the main class

```
public class RecyclerViewTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Fretes, FretesHolder> adapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerFretes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reclycler_view);


        mRecyclerFretes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerTest);
        mRecyclerFretes.setHasFixedSize(true);

        setupAdapter();
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("test");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Fretes> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Fretes>()
                        .setQuery(query, Fretes.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Fretes, FretesHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public FretesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_fretes, parent, false);

                return new FretesHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(FretesHolder holder, int position, Fretes model) {
                holder.setText_status(model.getmStatus());
                holder.setText_entrega(model.getmEntrega());
                holder.setText_coleta(model.getmColeta());
            }

        };
        mRecyclerFretes.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();

    }
}
```

I can't see what i'm missing or where its wrong, i will be grateful for some help. Thx

EDIT
I add this line the was missing on onCreate

```
 mRecyclerFretes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

And now i got this error :(

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type tiagov.rideabike1.Model.Fretes
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source:842)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zza(Unknown Source:0)
 at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
 at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:23)
 at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:14)
 at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:32)
 at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:45)
 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:103)
 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:118)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:710)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6567)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My database
[image: firebase]

Comment: What did you try to achieve the wanted solution?

Comment: get the data from firebase and put on ricycleview

Comment: show your database

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a FirebaseUI adapter to a location/query, it takes each **child node** and tries to map the properties of that child node to those in your class.

The child nodes under your location are `mColeta`, `mEntrega`, and `mStatus`. For each of those, Firebase creates a `Fretes` object and then tries to map the properties. Each of your child nodes only has a single value called `true`, so the mapping fails.

One way to make this work is to add a level to your JSON for the child node:

```
test
  -Lsdfiuhsaiu
    mColeta: "teste"
    mEntrega: "teste"
    mStatus: "teste"
```

With this structure, there is an extra level of nodes and your adapter can find the properties.